# High processing times for 5% of the total records using Spring 4.3.0 JDBC template to insert or update logic

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle12c, jdbctemplate, c3p0

Spring application reading around 200 events per minute from kafka topic and updating a single table with a where clause on a combination of two columns. Proper indexes are set up on the composite key.

The processing times for the record upsert is almost constant (<30ms).But during certain hours the processing times reach even 30 seconds for a single insert or update statement. There is no correlation with these high processing times and the peak load time as well.

So far we have checked the CPU utilisation , memory , thread count and row lock wait times as well.There seems to be no issues. Please suggest any other items to analyse this issue.

Tech stack used for db operations.
Spring 4.3.0
Spring Jdbc Template.
C3P0 Connection pool

Code snippet

```
String stmt= //construct query;
jdbcTemplate.update(stmt);
logger.info("Insert event is successful");
```

Sample Update:-

```
    UPDATE tablename
SET
    column1 = 'string1',
    column2 = 'string2',
    column3 = 0.1,
    column4 = 'string3',
    column5 = 0.1,
    column6 = 'string4',
    column7 = to_timestamp('2020-10-21_08.00.02_861', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS_FF')
WHERE
    compositeKeyA = 210
    AND compositeKeyB = '123';
```

Comment: Could you share more details about the "upsert"? How does the SQL look like -- are you possibly updating the primary key column? Are there triggers registered to the table?

Comment: Hi Mick .. I edited the main post to add the query.It is a dynamically constructed query.There is a db update query on the table.But the processing delay is happening for inserts too !! In the update statement the primary key is not updated.Thanks.

Comment: Really difficult to give advice with this little information. Can you gather Oracle's Statspack or AWR reports from the time period where there's slowness?

Comment: Did you tried changing to HikariCP? if you can't/won't, what is your db configuration?

Comment: Your question is pretty close to "how do I tune SQL statements", which is a large topic with no single, simple answer. To get started, you might want to find the SQL_IDs in the view `GV$SQL`, and then find how long they are taking and what resources they are waiting on from `GV$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY`. These issues often require a lot of information and a lot of back-and-forth, and don't often work well on Stack Overflow.

Comment: You shouldn't need to dynamically generate a different SQL statement per execution - just use one prepared statement and fill in the binds. It will automatically be faster as you won't have the over head of parsing, it will automatically be nicer on the DB memory as you won't have to store tons of unsharable plans in the SGA, it will almost certainly give you the same execution plan each time so you don't have to risk bad plans creeping in. And then you just have one sql_id you need to look for in `v$active_session_history` - if you've got the diagnostics pack licenced.

Comment: "processing time for the record upsert", what exactly do you identifiy as the "processing", reading and manipulating an upsert result? reading input and creating the needed upsert statement? or the actual upsert operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing the upsert with dynamically generated Prepared statement.

Looks like jdbcTemplate.update(stmt) creates a statement object for execution.I am guess it was due to absence of statement caching.

It seems to resolve the issue when we started using prepared statements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If its every time 30 seconds then it looks like a default value - for example wait time, idle time etc. Have you tried to increase the number of pooled connections and close unused connections ?